# Can't install update KB5025229 on Windows Server 2019 - Error 0x8007371b

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, windows-update, system-restore

Windows Server 2019 (OS Build 17763.4131).

Following a search for updates, I was offered the cumulative update KB5025229 which according to Microsoft contains fixes for security issues and some other bug-fixes.

Due to some other, now fixed issues, I have recently restored the Windows image using the following command:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:D:\sources`

The D:\ drive is an 8GB USB drive, which I prepared as install media using the tool named Rufus, using the latest downloadable Windows Server 2019 ISO.

Now, I am suspecting, because this installation has been in use for a good year now, and many other updates were installed on it just fine already, `DISM` replaced system files with the older ones from the ISO, which is apparently version `17763.3650`, as indicated by the filename: `17763.3650.221105-1748.rs5_release_svc_refresh_SERVER_EVAL_x64FRE_en-us.iso`.

This is, if I recall correctly, also the image I used to install the OS in the first place, around one year ago.

Now, I already tried everything possible, such as `chkdsk /X /F /R`, `sfc /scannow` as well as other options like stopping the `wuauserv` service, then deleting `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` and restarting the service to no avail.

Because I earlier noticed that the ISO version is older, and on the information page for KB5025229 it says:

`You must install the August 10, 2021 SSU (KB5005112) before installing the LCU.`

I went ahead and downloaded the servicing stack update from the Update Catalog, thinking it should already be installed, but to my surprise: It installed just fine, because if it was already installed, it wouldn't let me have installed the `.msu` file manually.

Now, however when I check the "Installed updates" section of the old Control Panel, the install date for the servicing stack update is all wrong, even though I just manually installed it, it shows 03/15/2023 instead of today, which is likely the date I automatically got it through Windows Update.

Note that installing this servicing stack update did **not** fix the error message I am getting, I even manually downloaded the update from the update catalog, and the installation seemingly goes well at first, then it just errors out by saying "Some updates were not installed."

Does anyone have any advice on what I can try next, or could it be that I have broken Windows completely by essentially downgrading some files, even though Windows still reports Build 17763.4131?

Theoretically, everything works fine, except for installing this one update - KB5025229.

All the other file verification methods report a clean installation too (chkdsk, DISM, sfc)

Should I just wait for the next LCU, since it might be a problem with the update itself, **as has happened before**?

The machine is a heavily fire-walled Workstation and runs just fine otherwise, but I too like receiving security updates, unless they are (possibly) broken.

Any advice on what I could try is highly appreciated.